# Sending a JSON file in Data Factory in Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have looked all over and can't find exactly what i am trying to do.  I am trying to send a json file to an external client.  The json file is a blob storage and is called kimblejob.json  I have it pointing to a Web activity that has the authenticaton already set as basic.  I have the json file under Datasets.  Now, every time I put something in the body, that is the what gets posted and not the file.  How do I get the file to post and not what is in the body?  What do I put in the body?  How do I direct it to send the json file and not the content of the body?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to docs it is not possible to copy data **to** a REST endpoint, only from. You can read more about that on this page `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest` on MS Docs.

You can also read about all supported data stores and formats on this link `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats`. If you scroll down to `Generic protocol` you will see that HTTP and REST is not supported as a sink.

[image: Screenshot showing the HTTP and REST is not supported as sinks in ADF]

Putting a dataset reference in a Web activity will only pass the metadata of the dataset and the linked service in your http POST - it will be up to the receiving API to know what to do with it.

In the past scenarios I've had where we need to upload data to a REST API I have landed the data temporarily in a storage account and then called a Azure Function to handle the upload to the REST endpoint.

Comment: Ok, let me make sure I clarify what I am trying to do.  I have a spreadsheet that I am converting it into a JSON file and then storing it in a storage blob.  Now from the storage blob, I would like to send that file to the client using Web activity.  I am able to to send the data if I copy the content of the file in the body, but how do I send a file instead and what do I put the in the body.  OR better question, How do I put the content of the file in the body of the Web activity.     Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well the short answer is you can’t. There is no way you can take the content of the JSON file and add it to the body of your HTTP call. It’s just not supported by that activity. I will adjust my answer to highlight this better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookup activitiy to look to that file. It will have 4 mb limit though . Output from lookup you can use it to provide body of web activitiy.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an output (JSON) from a Web Activity into the body of another Web Activity without having to use Copy data and blob storage.

Comment: This will not send the actual data. Only details of the dataset referenced by the activity.